# Pass html to viewChild in Angular 5

Tags: javascript, html, angular, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to pass html to a viewchild so it can add it to it's own components html. Until now I haven't found an answer how to solve this. 
I'm completely new to Angular, so most of the answers I've read on alot of topics I don't quite understand which makes it pretty hard.

The parent is using NgbModal (@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap) to open a bootstrap modal. Since I don't want to keep repeating the same code for the modal itself all trough the project, I want to use a component for it. The modal component (viewchild) is working, except that I can't manage to pass html to the modal component so it can use the html to fill in the modal-body.

Triggering the modal like:

```
this.modalService.open(content, options).result;
```

Is there some way to use the inner html for example like:

```
<app-modal #modal>
    <img src="test.png" alt="test" />
</app-modal>
```

So the image will be the content of the bootstrap modal.

Comment: check this [article](https://medium.com/@angularlicious/dynamically-loaded-bootstrap-4-modal-component-powered-by-angular-6621f5fd3173) would help.

Comment: added answer try out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to finally fix it by wrapping the included component into ng-template.

Parent component's html including the module/viewChild:

```
<ng-template #imageFileModalContent let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
    <app-modal>
        <img [src]="msgFile" />
    </app-modal>
</ng-template>
```

Modal's html (viewChild):

```
<div class="modal-body form-group">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

Comment: It also needs a `ng-container` for the `ng-template` to be shown! something like: `<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="imageFileModalContent; context: ctx}">`, when we have `ctx = {close: 'something', dismiss: 'another'}` in the component class (`.ts` file)

Answer (score 1):

Read : [**Content Projection**](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/components/content-projection/)

you can make use of [ng-containt : Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nfig6b?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.model.component.html)

**app-modal.component.html** (selector will be app-modal)

```
<div class="dynamiccont">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

when you use this component like this

```
<app-modal #modal>
  <img src="test.png" alt="test" />
</app-modal>
```

---

this will work for you, key part is to make use of `ng-content` which helps you to include content.

Comment: I've added ng-content tag into the modal-body of the modal component like you said but it's not showing in the modal, the container in which the image should be stays empty somehow. I can't find any differences or so why it shouldn't work. I tried to use selector (select attribute) on the ng-content tag and tried it without, both resulting in an empty modal.

Comment: @MirandaBreekweg - you mean to say image tag comes but its not loading image ?

Comment: @MirandaBreekweg - if image is not loading then path must be wrong

Comment: I meant that the whole image tag is not there in the modal, so the ng-content tag is basically replaced with nothing.

Comment: @MirandaBreekweg - simple working demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nfig6b?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.model.component.html

Comment: Thank you for the demo. Currently I have it just like that. I also noticed that the app-modal contents are not showing up in the DOM. Also tried just text instead of an image.

Comment: @MirandaBreekweg - can you put your code there in stackbiz and check .... because that should work